# What is the most beneficial buff for a Juggernaut Tank?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

When you finish the second chapter of your class quest, your class buff is available to every character in your Legacy. Since I am close to finishing Chapter 3 and want to level a new Toon, I am wondering which buff would benefit my Juggernaut Tank the most, as in which class would be the most beneficial to finish Chapter 2 with.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, just in case you weren't sure: finishing Act 2 with a character unlocks their faction-appropriate base-class buff for all your characters, *including characters of the opposite faction*. Any Republic characters you make will get the Knight buff in addition to their regular buff, and if you decide to level a Consular (for example), your Juggernaut will get the Inquisitor buff once your Consular finishes Act 2.

**Either the Inquisitor/Consular buff or the Trooper/BH buff.**

The Inquisitor/Consular buff gives +5% to primary stats (Str/Will/Aim/Cun) and, more importantly +10% internal & elemental damage reduction. The boost to primary stats means you'll do a little bit more damage and therefore generate a little bit more threat. Internal & elemental damage aren't nearly as common as physical damage, but 10% damage resistance can really make a difference in a long fight with a boss who inflicts those damage types regularly.

The Trooper/BH buff gives +5% Endurance. More endurance means more HP. More HP means more "cushion" when tanking; taking a crit, the healer messing up their rotation, you messing up your cooldown rotation, etc. are all less risky because you can take more hits before going down.

**It doesn't really matter, though.**

If you're in a flashpoint, odds are the 4 people will have all 4 buffs covered between them. If you're in a raid, it's a sure thing. Picking up additional buffs is more of an aid when soloing; that means it's actually *more* beneficial if you're planning on leveling multiple characters than it is for people who intend to concentrate on a single max-level character.